Did Moses' face shine forever until his death?
Exodus 34:29-35 says that Moses' face shined after he was in the presence of G-d.  Did Moses' face shine forever until his death or did this pass after a certain amount of time much prior to his death?

Rabbeinu Bahya holds the opinion that due to the spiritual level Moshe Rabbeinu was on, his face shined even after talking to G-d:

והנה קרן עור פניו, “and behold! the skin of his face had become radiant.” We know of the light which represents wisdom and we know light which emerges out of darkness. The former kind of light is the light G’d employed to create the universe. Concerning that light our sages have said that it preceded the first directive of G’d in the Book of Genesis, i.e. “let there be light.” This light which was employed as a tool in G’d’s work of creation is known as ראשית. Moses attained this light in his heart, and it was this light which separated him from all other prophets making him superior to all of them.
The light which emerges out of darkness is the essence of fire, it is known as אור מוגרש, ”light which has been expelled.” This is the light which was applied to Moses, the light which is here called as radiating from the face of Moses. He acquired this ability to radiate light as a result of obtaining the second set of Tablets whereas he had not achieved this ability when he received the first set of Tablets when he was described as “turning and descending from the mountain” (32,15). During the period when the first set of Tablets was being prepared the people had still been under the spiritually uplifting experience of the revelation, everyone of them having been a party to insights never before granted to man. Now that they were no longer on that spiritual level and G’d had even warned them that “no one will ascend (spiritually) with you” (34,3), they would not have credited Moses with continuing to be on such a level had there not been some visible evidence of that. G’d provided this when he made Moses’ skin emit rays of light.

